# How to use MarkLogic REST API from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, marklogic

Is there example code or an example project how make REST API calls to marklogic server from AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking at the MarkLogic Slush template project:

https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node

It provides a complete stack, including deployment scripts, with MarkLogic REST-api as back-end, a thin NodeJS layer in between, and an AngularJS front-end.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MarkLogic Slush template (which looks very interesting and worth looking at if you ask me) you could simply create an AngularJS service that would use $http ([AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)) and call the ML REST API.

Comment: any idea why I keep getting base64 .ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined. Here it code I have controller("getRestulsCtrl", function ($http){
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']  = 'Basic' + Base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');
 $http.get("http://localhost:8011/v1/search?q=tandon&options=facet&start=6&format=json")
 .success(function (data) {
  console.log(data)
 })

})
;

Comment: any idea why I keep getting base64

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on from just a short snippet but ReferenceError means that Base64 is not recognized by the angularjs app. Try adding an angularjs module for this (https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64). I also think you are doing this incorrectly, the correct way to do this is to create a service(or a factory) for example MLRest which would have number of functions that would return desired actions i.e. REST calls. Then from the controller(s) you include the service and use it there with the $http promise.

Comment: thanks you are correct eventually I will put all this code in proper structure. right now I am just trying get a sense of how things work. Thanks a lot for your help.